# implicit conversion from T and string

Tags: c#, .net, implicit-conversion

I currently have a generic class which allows the use of an expression as the value.

```
public class Expression<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public string ExpressionText { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator Expression<T>(string input)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            return null;

        if (input.StartsWith("="))
            return new Expression<T> { ExpressionText = input };

        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
        T value = (T)converter.ConvertFromString(input);

        return new Expression<T> { Value = value };
    }

    public static implicit operator Expression<T>(T value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        return new Expression<T> { Value = value };
    }
```

What I would like to be able to do is to set properties using implicit conversions from both T and from string. However if the expression is of type string, the compiler cannot decide which conversion to use.

Is there a clever way around this?

Thanks,

Sean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to keep both implicit operators and expect to work with an `Expression<string>` because of the [better conversion rule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691339(v=vs.71).aspx)

> Given an implicit conversion C1 that converts from a type S to a type
>   T1, and an implicit conversion C2 that converts from a type S to a
>   type T2, the better conversion of the two conversions is determined as
>   follows:
>
> - If T1 and T2 are the same type, neither conversion is better.
> - If S is T1, C1 is the better conversion.
> - If S is T2, C2 is the better conversion.
> - If an implicit conversion from T1 to T2 exists, and no implicit conversion from T2 to T1 exists, C1 is the better conversion.
> - If an implicit conversion from T2 to T1 exists, and no implicit conversion from T1 to T2 exists, C2 is the better conversion.
> - If T1 is sbyte and T2 is byte, ushort, uint, or ulong, C1 is the better conversion.
> - If T2 is sbyte and T1 is byte, ushort, uint, or ulong, C2 is the better conversion.
> - If T1 is short and T2 is ushort, uint, or ulong, C1 is the better conversion.
> - If T2 is short and T1 is ushort, uint, or ulong, C2 is the better conversion.
> - If T1 is int and T2 is uint, or ulong, C1 is the better conversion.
> - If T2 is int and T1 is uint, or ulong, C2 is the better conversion.
> - If T1 is long and T2 is ulong, C1 is the better conversion.
> - If T2 is long and T1 is ulong, C2 is the better conversion.
> - Otherwise, neither conversion is better.
>
> If an implicit conversion C1 is defined by these rules to be a better
>   conversion than an implicit conversion C2, then it is also the case
>   that C2 is a worse conversion than C1.

With an `Expression<string>` you are clearly in the first case, the compiler won't choose for you and will [just stop there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

> If there is not exactly one function member that is better than all
>   other function members, then the function member invocation is
>   ambiguous and a compile-time error occurs.

So you won't be able to handle with with conversion operators only; either create additional methods to deal with string explicitly, convert the string to T outside of the operator or create a wrapping abstraction that would be able to tranport T, a string representation of T or the ExpressionText value and convert from it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I have decided to create a static method which will handle conversion from string and use the implicit conversion for T as this will be the most commonly used of the two.

Answer (score 2):

try this one.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Expression<string> str = "1";

        }
    }
    public class Expression<T>
    {
        public T Value { get; set; }
        public string ExpressionText { get; set; }



        public static implicit operator Expression<T>(T value)
        {
            if (value is string) {
                string input = value.ToString();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
                    return null;

                if (input.StartsWith("="))
                    return new Expression<T> { ExpressionText = input };

                var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
                T tValu = (T)converter.ConvertFromString(input);

                return new Expression<T> { Value = tValu };
            }
            else if (value == null)
                return null;

            return new Expression<T> { Value = value };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining a generic convert and specific type convert you are actually generating ambiguity. But you don't need define the specific (string) convert as the generic one already covers all cases.

```
public class Expression<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public string ExpressionText { get; set; }

    public static Expression<T> Convert(string input)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            return null;

        if (input.StartsWith("="))
            return new Expression<T> { ExpressionText = input };

        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
        T value = (T)converter.ConvertFromString(input);

        return new Expression<T> { Value = value };
    }

    public static implicit operator Expression<T>(T value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        var str = value as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            return Convert(str);
        else
            return new Expression<T> { Value = value };
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code just returns null if `value` is not a `string`

Comment: @DarkWanderer Oh! yes, thank you for pointing out this, I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing prevents you from using a run-time type check:

```
if (input is string) 
    return new Expression<T>(input as string); // delegate to explicit constructor
```